# Unable to use nuget packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have written some code that uses the following packages:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

But when I compile the code there is a few errors related to the following code, that I suppose it is written by the "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" package:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
namespace GetDatafromBlob0201
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class SqlDatabaseSetup
    {
        [AssemblyInitialize()]
        public static void InitializeAssembly(TestContext ctx)
        {
            // Setup the test database based on setting in the
            // configuration file
            SqlDatabaseTestClass.TestService.DeployDatabaseProject();
            SqlDatabaseTestClass.TestService.GenerateData();
        }
    }
}
```

Where "using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting" throws an error.
I have tried installing the NuGet package, but that didn't solve the error.

These are the errors I get:
[Errors after compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoWon.png)

Mostly CS0246.
The last one indicates that the reference could not be used.

I am also noticing a warning sign under my proyect, on "Packeges" and also on "Assembly":

1. The one on Assembly its on Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components, Version= 16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL. It doesn't give me details on the warning.
2. The one on Packages is on Microsoft.Data.Tools.UnitTest and it says: Package 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.UnitTest' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to help you with this without knowing the errors that are occurring. So it would help if you updated your post with the relevant ones here.

Comment: try `update-package -reinstall`

Comment: *throws an error.* - if you get errors, show the errors. Please read [ask] to get an idea what to put into your questions.

Comment: That code is not "written by the 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' package". That code uses the elements cointained in that nuget package to configure some automated testing. As others have already said, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66010158/edit) and add the errors you get.

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback.I have updated the post with the errors. Where can I use this code? "update-package -reinstall"

Comment: see the lines that give an error and let the mouse over the risk to see what visual studio recommends adding another using

Comment: Visual Studio doesnt recommend adding another "using", it sais IDE0005 "Using directive is unnecessary"

Comment: @TeresaReyAlonso, any update about this issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Im sorry for the delay. Your answer solved my problem. Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test with your csproj file and install any nuget packages, I did not get any build errors.

These are the nuget packages which I have installed.

[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/)

[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/)

[Microsoft.Data.Tools.UnitTest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Tools.UnitTest/16.0.62004.28040)

**So** please make sure that there is no red error lines on your code editor.

**Then**, close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

**After that**, restart VS and your project, then, run `update-package -reinstall` command under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

## Update 1

I think you have created a **MSTest  test project(net core)** project rather than a **unit test project(net framework)** project.

**In my side**, I used `unit test project(net framework)`, and all work well.

**Actually**, some of your nuget packages are for `net framework`. That is what the warning `NU1701` did. But you can ignore that warning since it is normal that you have install the package into net core rather than net framework. And the package can be used under net core. And it is just a little warning rather than a error.

Due to that, `update-package -reinstall` cannot work for new-sdk project(your situaiton) and only for `packages.config` with `net framework`.

Maybe try these:

**1)Besides**, I think `Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components.dll` is from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB`. You have used some dlls from there. And due to some situations, these do not work and you should readd them on your current environment.

**And** first, please delete any references from here:

[image]

**Then**, readd these dlls from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB` to check if your project still have these errors.

Or you could remove `Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components.dll` from there to fix it.

If these do not help, maybe try nuget packages like what I said above:

**1)** [clean all nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`

**2)** to remove that warning, please add this xml node under csproj file of the unit test project.

[image]

[image]

**3)** Or you could try to use `unit test project(net framework)` project and then add your code there and I ensure that could work.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your clear answer. I'm afraid it didnt work, though. I get the same errors as before, and now I have a new warning: NU1701 Package 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.UnitTest' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: I am also noticing a warning sign under my proyect, on "Packeges" and also on "Assembly", The one on Assembly its on Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components, Version= 16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL, the one on "package" is the same as the NU1701 warning

Comment: Actually, you should create a `unit test project(net framework)` rather than `MSTest  test project(net core)`.  From your description,  you have created a net core test project. Some of your nuget packages are for `net framework`. That is what the warning `NU1701` did. Actually, you can ignore that warning. That is normal since you have install the package into net core rather than net framework. And the package can be used under net core. You can use try my function on the answer. And I have updated my answer and you can check it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed your steps and it works. I have to be honest, Im not sure why, but this allows me to keep working on my code, so again, thanks a lot for the clear answer and instructions.